# How can i search a foreign character in access database using C#

Tags: ms-access, c#-4.0

Hi
I have a access database that contains foreign characters(Hebrew language). 
How can i search the values in the column by using c#?
This is my code:

```
SELECT * FROM "table name" WHERE column_name LIKE '%שגל%'
```

I'm getting this error: `Syntax Error in SQl statement`

Can anyone please afford your time and help me in this?
שגל- this is the Hebrew language.

Comment: Have a look at the Help file for the StrConv() function. I'm not entirely certain that's the solution, but the functions related to that allow you to deal with Unicode data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the bug.
I changed the column name from _region to property_region.

Why _region makes error, Is it a Keyword