# search a foreign character in access database using C#

Tags: ms-access, c#

I have an Access database that contains foreign characters(Hebrew language).

How can I search the values in the column using C#? This is my code:

```
SELECT * FROM "table name" WHERE column_name LIKE '%שגל%'
```

I'm getting this error:

> Syntax Error in SQL statement

Can anyone please afford your time and help me in this?

שגל- this is the Hebrew language.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i search a foreign character in access database using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817924/how-can-i-search-a-foreign-character-in-access-database-using-c)

Comment: I wonder if the string comparison situation is complicated by text-directionality issues?  I was trying to wrap each character in a pair of brackets [] but could not get the second character inside brackets. I copied and pasted the string, and placed the cursor insertion point before the third character (i.e. far right character from western alphabet perspective), but when I type the closing bracket, the screen renders an [ open bracket instead. And when I type an open bracket, it renders a closing bracket.'%[ש][ג][ל]%'.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the bug. I changed the column name from _region to property_region.

Why _region makes error, Is it a Keyword

Thanks for ur answer Rik, How to specify the Codepage for access

Comment: Reserved words always cause problems. You can avoid the problem by enclosing them in square brackets, [Region]. I'm not sure whether you're saying your table was called `_region` or `region`. The undersctore characters sometimes cause the need for square brackets (as to any number of special characters in an object name, like #, ?, etc.), so it may not be a reserved-word problem after all. I use CamelCase in my object names and avoid spaces and underscores. I know a lot of people from other db environments are allergic to mixed case, because other db engines may not support it.

Comment: @David: thanks David,  if u can pls help me in this thread : http://superuser.com/questions/277384/grid-view-collapes-the-data-while-populating

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the codepage for the access database?

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-the-hebrew-code-page-HP005257928.aspx